# I see this error when I trying to update my post in my blog project in Laravel 8 'Creating default object from empty value', what does that mean?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

when I trying to edit my post in blog project then above error is occured.
that is my code:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // 
    $data = Post::find($request->id);
    $data->title = $request->input('title');
    $data->description = $request->input('description');
    $data->update();
      return redirect('/index')->withMessage('successfully published');
    }
```

And that is my routes-

Route::get('posts/edit/{edit}',[PostController::class,'edit']);

Route::post('/update',[PostController::class,'update']);